# Update column of html table like a preview using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to update a html table single column to show preview of new name.html table contains two columns.

I have a drop down list that shows different panels of renaming rules made a rules and function return me new string.

The problem is how i show the preview of new name with jquery ajax calls

The function I use to generate html is

```js
$(document).on("click", "#childern li", function() {

      var subFolderID = $(this).attr("id");

      var objlst = $(this);
      var request;
      request = $.ajax({
        context: this,
        url: url,
        method: "POST",

        data: {
          'id': subFolderID
        },
        ContentType: 'application/json'
      });
      request.done(function(response) {

        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        var trHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0, l = result.length; i < l; i++) {
          trHTML += '<tr><td class="col-md-2">' + result[i].name +
            '</td><td class="col-md-2">' + result[i].name +
            '</td></tr>';

        }


        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);

      });
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and produce a [mcve] - currently your code does not have enough information. What is expected and actual result? Any errors in console?